# Window Open not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, portal

I am trying to make a help window on some forms on Microsoft Dynamics Portals, it has its own CMS to build a web app.

This window does not work on IE11 or Edge because of differnt "errors".

First this is my JavaScript function to load the window for "most" of browsers:

```
function openWindow(text) {
    var textNode = document.createElement('p');
    textNode.innerHTML = text;
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('.NET') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') > 0) {
        var window1 = window.showModalDialog('', [1, 4], "dialogwidth: 450; dialogheight: 300; resizable: no");
        window1.appendChild(textNode);
    } else {
        var window1 = window.open('','Ayuda de Formulario','toolbar=no,width=700,height=500,left=500,top=200,status=no,scrollbars=no,resize=no');
        window1.document.body.append(textNode);
    }
}
```

I use `window.showModalDialog` because of IE compatibility.

This is where I capture the mouse click on an image:

```
$('.form-helper').click(function() {
    var language = $('html').attr('lang').split('-')[0];
    getFormHelper($(this), language);
});
```

And this is where I load the form helper:

```
window.formHelpers = loadFormHelpers();
function loadFormHelpers() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/API', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
       if(xhr.status == 200) {
         var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.response),
             results = jsonResponse.results;
             window.formHelpers = results;
       } else {
        console.error('API Error');
       }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

And of course, the first to running:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadFormHelpers();
});
```

I am getting on Microsoft Edge:
[image: edge]

And on IE11, I am getting a blank window, on Developer tools:
[image: IE11]

> Which says ***The method does not accept property or method "append"***

Any suggestions to make this work on all the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to use `appendChild` instead. like this:
`window1.document.body.appendChild(textNode);`

Comment: I have tried that before, it didn't work. but I tried again, still the same. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I made it with `window1.document.write(text)` instead.

It is like:

```
function openWindow(text) {
    var window1 = window.open('','Ayuda de Formulario','toolbar=no,width=700,height=500,left=500,top=200,status=no,scrollbars=no,resize=no');
    window1.document.write(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Portals comes with Bootstrap, should you try use the Bootstrap model which might give an nicer overall effect.

Example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there documentation which lists all libraries supported/included with Dynamics Portals?